# PHP get all headers Capitalize first symbols

Tags: php

I knew that the PHP method "getallheaders" change my custom headers. I spent a lot of time to understand why my script doesn't get any headers. The problem lies with my hosting, but in my local server all headers works fine without renaming.

For example:

```
dupId -> Dupid
dup_id -> Dupid
```

Why? How can I resolve it? I want to send 'dupId' from JS and get 'dupId' in server side.

Comment: getallheaders() is an alias of apache_request_headers(), is your hosting using apache ?

Comment: @rasim I am wondering why you have to put data inside headers. Sorry to pull up such an old post. Please share your solution if you were able to solve this issue. Just curious.